# JS form validation not working in IE

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Simple JS form validation does not seem to be working in IE. Any help would be grand. It seems to be submitting the form rather then giving me an alert when nothing is entered into the email field. works as intended in Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari, Just NOT in IE.

HTML

```
<form action="index.php" name="loginForm" onsubmit="return validateLoginForm();" method="post" >
    <div class="formBg">
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="formPos" value="" placeholder="Email" />
      <div class="loginText"><a href="#" class="linkOne">Forgot your password?</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="formBg">
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="formPos" value="" placeholder="Password" />
      <div class="loginText">Keep me logged in</div>
    </div>
    <div id="loginBtnFrame">
      <div id="loginBtn">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="loginFormBtn" value=" " tabindex="3" />
      </div>
      <div class="slider-frame"><span class="slider-button">no</span></div>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

Javascript

```
function validateLoginForm()
{
var x=document.forms["loginForm"]["email"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("email must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: did you try `var x = document.getElementById('email').value;` ?

Comment: @scibuff Yes. Does not work. =(

Comment: are you sure there are no javascript errors in IE - that would cause the validation not to run; try `function validateLoginForm(){ alert('here'); return false; }`

Comment: @scibuff yes that works fine in IE.

Comment: ok, then just start adding one thing at a time as see where it breaks, e.g. first add `alert(document.forms["loginForm"])` then `alert(document.forms["loginForm"]["email"]);` then `alert(document.forms["loginForm"]["email"].value);` etc

Comment: Works for me in IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/qK7gk/

Comment: Funny, this code works in IE9 as expected. With what version you have been testing?

Comment: @AlexK. The JSFiddle works for me too.  ha ha.  Using IE 8 and 9 to test. wonder what it could be. Ill do what scibuff sugested.

Comment: Likely its something else in the page, you will need to expand your example

Comment: @AlexK. seems to be conflicting with my JQuery somehow. When I remove the jquery it works. Any ideas?

Comment: That links works for me and includes jq

Comment: @AlexK. I just added more into the js.
'(x==null || x=="" || x=="Email")'
and now it works. Only problem is it deletes my placeholder after the alert.

Comment: In IE8 I get "A problem displaying countryclubrentalsinc.com caused Internet Explorer to refresh the webpage using Compatibility View" .. possibly because `placeholder` isnt valid in xhtml (its html5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those that may hit the same issue.

I found that IE simple form validation conflicts with HTML or some Jquery 'placeholders'. I got around it by adding  '(x==null || x=="" || x=="Email")' to the JS command. Where 'Email' is the placeholder text. Now working as intended.